# Use Indirect/Index Match to Pull Data From Multiple Sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook which contains a master sheet along with 200+ tabs which I am trying to pull data from.  The master sheet contains store numbers in column A, and various headers for different products in range B1:T1.  Each store has its own tab & the tabs are named after each store number.  I am looking to match the store number in column A of the master sheet to each tab name (store number), then match the headers in the master sheet to the headers in each tab and retrieve the values below each header.  I am thinking I need to use the indirect formula to match the store number to each tab name and indexmatch to pull my data over, but I am struggling to put these pieces together.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!
[Here's what my master sheet looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EvRF.png)

[Example store data that I want to pull over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUpSH.png)

Comment: Will the information you need to copy always be in the second row? or can there bee more information?

Comment: Are you looking for a VBA solution or a worksheet function solution?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

[Sample view here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DScmd.jpg)

[Formula view here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkz7W.jpg)

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: you're welcome... pls vote for my answer and thank you too! :)

Answer (score 0):

hope the below link will help you :)

[Index Match formula](http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match-match/)